# procedimiento mysql me trae toda la tabla y no solo los parametros que envio

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedure

Buenas estoy practicando con mysql y realize un procedimiento de login
algo simple pero cuando ejecuto me trae toda la tabla y
no solo los parametros que estoy enviando.
si alquien me podria decir que estoy haciendo mal .
Gracias

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE login(
IN usuario varchar(50),
IN clave VARCHAR(50)
 )
BEGIN
      SELECT *
      FROM usuario
      WHERE usuario = usuario && clave = clave;      
END$$

call  login('jose','654321')
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando haces referencia a `usuario` el ejecutor de MySQL no sabe si te refieres a la columna o al parámetro, y decide por el contexto mas cercano que es la tabla.
Cambia el nombre de los parámetros:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE login(
IN pUsuario varchar(50),
IN pClave VARCHAR(50)
 )
BEGIN
      SELECT *
      FROM usuario
      WHERE usuario = pUsuario && clave = pClave;      
END$$
```